# p4v crash on stream graph with unicode(utf8,bom,noBom)

Tags: unicode, perforce, p4v

I install perforce server to centos 7.4 with 'p4 -u xxx init -C0 -xi'  P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2017.2/1579154 (2017/10/12).

when I connect to the server and view stream graph, the p4v crash **on stream graph view.**
I think it relates to connection character encoding(utf8 etc..), because after change character encoding, p4v doesn't crash until reconnect.

this problem occurs p4v 2017.1, 2017.2, but **2015.2 has no problem.**

anybody has a same problem?